# Find the limit with two equations

Tags: real-analysis, limits, functions

Assume that, for any $m,n\in R$ we have $$f(m+n+1)=f(m)+f(n)$$

Also, $f(0)=1$

Show that $$\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(h)-1}{h}=1$$

The original question is using the two conditions to prove that $f(x)=1+x$.

But I want to see whether it can be solved by finding its derivative.

I don't know what I can do next. Is that possible to find its derivative through equations is given?

Comment: How do you mean solved by finding its derivative? Until you know the function, it is not clear it is differentiable at all. In fact, it is not clear it is continuous. You cannot take a derivative until you know the derivative exists. Of course, by the time you know that, you have already solved the problem.

Comment: So the first step is showing it is continuous? Thanks, I am trying.

Comment: I don't think it is possible to show that such a function, that satisfies the above 2 conditions is always continuous.

Comment: $g(x):=f(x-1)$ satisfies [$g(x+y)=g(x)+g(y)$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_functional_equation), which has discontinuous solutions (under ZFC), and continuous solutions of the form $g(x)=cx$ only (which is shown without using derivatives).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By $m=x,\ n=y$, $m=x,\ n=0$ you have
$$f(x+y)-f(x)=f(y)-f(0)$$
Now, if
$$\limsup_{y\to 0+} f(y)-f(0)≠0$$
or
$$\liminf_{y\to 0+} f(y)-f(0)≠0$$
you would have that (iterating the previous relation)
$$\forall x, \ \limsup_{y\to 0+} f(x+y)-f(x)=+\infty$$
or
$$\forall x, \ \liminf_{y\to 0+} f(x+y)-f(x)=-\infty$$
Which is not tecnically a contradiction but maybe can bring to one